# String.format replacing list of string and integer

Tags: java, string-formatting

I have the following string `%1s %1d %2s %2d %3d %3s` and the two following array `["x","y","z"]` `[10,11,12]`.

I would like to get the following output : `x 10 y 11 12 z`

Is there any elegant solution to do this in Java ?

The solution should not depends on the number of arguments or the size of the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String format = "%s %d %s %d %d %s";
String[] arrayString = {"x","y","z"};
int[] arrayInt = {10,11,12};
System.out.format(format, arrayString[0], arrayInt[0], arrayString[1], arrayInt[1], arrayInt[2], arrayString[2]);
```

EDIT: I'd do it this way to be absolutely general:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] stringArray = {
        "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"
    };

    Boolean[] boolArray = {
            true, false, true
    };

    Integer[] intArray = {1, 2};

    int[] outputOrder = {0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0};
    Object[][] outputContent = {stringArray, boolArray, intArray};
    System.out.println(formatMyOutput(outputContent, outputOrder));         
}

private static String formatMyOutput(Object[][] printingArrays, int[] outputOrder) {
    StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    int[] currentlyPrinting = new int[printingArrays.length];
    boolean notFirst = false;
    for (int indexToPrint : outputOrder) {
        if (notFirst) {
            outputBuilder.append(" ");
        } else {
            notFirst = true;
        }
        outputBuilder.append(
            printingArrays[indexToPrint][currentlyPrinting[indexToPrint]++]
                .toString()
        );
    }
    return outputBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for a dynamic solution, not depending on the number of arguments.

Comment: Nop, I expect the same order as described in the formatted string.

Comment: If there is 4 elements in the lists, what do you expect as output?

Comment: I think that, in that case, you should code it by yourself. I could give you code snippet how to do that if you need help.

Comment: I added you example, you can copy it and reuse it in any situation for any number of outputs. Only restriction is that you can not use primitive types but `Integer` instead of `int` and so on,